# C++ extern Глобальные переменные

Tags: c++, global-variables, линковка, дублирование, extern

Всем привет! Я сейчас только изучаю С++ и делаю небольшую программку на С++ (с библиотекой SDL2) и столкнулся с проблемой линковки глобальных переменных в файлах (в том числе глобальных функций). Я хочу добавить .h файл(схема файлов ниже) "extensions" с глобальной функцией в файл buttons.h так, чтобы она была видна и для всех других файлов (в том числе в main) ну или как минимум для main.cpp, view.cpp и buttons.cpp. Вопрос, как это сделать, чтобы не было multiple definitions или redifinition?

И сразу аналогичный вопрос: (общий вопрос)как работать с extern переменными, чтобы они были видны всюду? А точнее:

1. Как объявлять глобальную для всех файлов переменную, имеющую например тип menu* до того, как был объявлен menu.h? forward definition в buttons.h? Но тогда forward будет и в view.cpp и в buttons.cpp,разве не дублирование получается?
2. А если я хочу объявить глобальную переменную где-то далеко, например аж в main.cpp или menu.h, то она будет видна в buttons.h или buttons.cpp?

[image: Схема подключения файлов проекта]

Comment: Перепишите весь код без `extern` переменных, они ни для чего не нужны.

Comment: @user7860670 как это не нужны, если я хочу глобальную переменную/функцию, которую должны видеть все классы, то почему нет?

Comment: Глобальные функции - это нормально, а переменные нет. Еще почитайте про паттерн синглетон.

Comment: @user7860670 я прекрасно знаю о том, что глобальными переменными нельзя злоупотреблять, но здесь она и вправду нужна, ибо это будет указатель на рендерер, который будет рендерить полностью всю картинку(будет рисовать все),а также нужна другая глобальная переменная, чтобы  передать в menu.h какие-то данные из buttons.h

Comment: Во-первых передавать что-то можно не между файлами, а между областями видимости. Так что делайте синглетон. А еще лучше - передавайте явно.

Comment: @user7860670 а можно узнать как это делается? Ну или ссылку на статью какую-нибудь по этой теме? Буду благодарен.

Comment: Заводишь `renderer.h` и `renderer.cpp`, в `.h` пишешь `extern Renderer g_renderer;`, в `.cpp` - `Renderer g_renderer;`. Дальше подключай `renderer.h` везде, где нужна эта глобальная переменная.

Comment: @Osyotr т.е. в каждом cpp файле, где нужна будет переменная, объявленная в другом файле, нужно писать при объявлении extern,а потом иницализировать?

Comment: Определение и инициализация переменной должны быть только в одном cpp файле. Объявлять можно сколько угодно раз, но объявления должны совпадать и быть extern. (совет: не нужно писать в каждом файле `extern MyType g_MyVar;`, для этого есть заголовочные файлы)

Comment: @Osyotr т.е. даже если прям в одном h или даже cpp файле два раза написать extern int a; extern int a; то ничего не сломается?

Comment: Да, объявлять можно сколько угодно раз, но определять - только один.